# Syntax error in mysql query

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with that query ?

```
SELECT
    null,
    DISTINCT(email),  
    2,
    SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 32) 
    from users where sex = 'male'
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(email),

Comment: Interchanging the order of `null` and `DISTINCT(email)` will work. eg
    `DISTINCT(email),  null,`. `DISTINCT` should come before any column name

Comment: @Shakti Singh: `DISTINCT(email)` should be equivalent to `DISTINCT (email)` that should be equivalent to `DISTINCT email`. The parenthesis are not needed and don't serve any purpose in this context other that confuse.

Comment: @Aleksi: Use of parenthesis is completely based on requirement.

Comment: @Shakti Singh: How does it help e.g. in the following query  `select distinct(b), a from (select 11 a, 22 b, 33 c union all select 12, 22, 33) data;` the parenthesis do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent of using a distinct is to declare that duplicate rows should be dropped. Distinct is used right after the select

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    null,
    email,  
    2,
    SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 32) 
FROM users 
WHERE sex = 'male'
```

I'd guess that dropping duplicate rows fails in the previous query as it contains a random column value. However, the distinct email addresses can be selected in a subquery and the rest of the columns added afterwards:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    null,
    email,  
    2,
    SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 32) 
 FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT email
       FROM users
       WHERE sex = 'male'
 ) males
```

See [MySQL select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html).